# Load entities without locking rows in database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is there an option in JPA to load an entity (or a list of) without locking the database? 
I would like to be able to do it in just a few methods.
Also is it possible for JPA to load the entity without locking the database, BUT when anything change on that entity, just then it lock the row in the database? Validating the state of course, if the entity is already changed in the database throws an exception of invalid state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an option in JPA to load an entity (or a list of) without locking the database?

Entities can be loaded by means of different EntityManager's calls:

- `EntityManager.find`
- `EntityManager.createQuery`
- `EntityManager.createNamedQuery`
- `EntityManager.createNativeQuery`

You don't need to use `LockModeType.None` explicitly in these calls. This is the default option in JPA represented by `LockModeType.None`.

> Also is it possible for JPA to load the entity without locking the database, BUT when anything change on that entity, just then it lock the row in the database?

Entities can be locked by means of different calls:

- `EntityManager.find`
- `EntityManager.lock`
- `EntityManager.refresh`
- `Query.setLockMode`

I would say it is possible but not guaranteed by JPA as it depends on the persistence provider (vendor-specific) and type of locking being used.

Anyway such scenario may have look like this:

```java
// begin tx
...
SomeEntity e = em.find(SomeEntity.class, id);
// change the entity
em.lock(e, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC); // LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT
...
// commit tx
```

Now, it depends on a persistence provider whether locking will be eager (when lock is called) or deferred (when tx completes). Keep in mind that another transaction may lock the entity as the first one and you will end up with rollback.

From ***JPA Specification 2.0***, chapter ***3.4.4.1 OPTIMISTIC, OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT***:

> If transaction `T1` calls `lock(entity, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC)` on a
>   versioned object, the entity manager must ensure that neither of the
>   following phenomena can occur:
>
> - P1 (Dirty read): Transaction `T1` modifies a row. Another transaction `T2` then reads that row and obtains the modified value,
>     before `T1` has committed or rolled back. Transaction `T2` eventually
>     commits successfully; it does not matter whether `T1` commits or rolls
>     back and whether it does so before or after `T2` commits.
> - P2 (Non-repeatable read): Transaction `T1` reads a row. Another transaction `T2` then modifies or deletes that row, before `T1` has
>     committed. Both transactions eventually commit successfully.
>
> This will generally be achieved by the entity manager acquiring a lock
>   on the underlying database row. **While with optimistic concurrency,
>   long-term database read locks are typically not obtained immediately,
>   a compliant implementation is permitted to obtain an immediate lock
>   (so long as it is retained until commit completes). If the lock is
>   deferred until commit time, it must be retained until the commit
>   completes.** Any implementation that supports repeatable reads in a
>   way that prevents the above phenomena is permissible
>
> If transaction `T1` calls
>   `lock(entity,LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)` on a versioned
>   object, the entity manager must avoid the phenomena P1 and P2 (as with
>   `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC`) and must also force an update (increment)
>   to the entity's version column. **A forced version update may be
>   performed immediately, or may be deferred until a flush or commit.**

Comment: Cool, that sounds nice, but it seems to me that using the lock method after loading the entity will not prevent the query from waiting to acquire the lock before delivering the entity to my control, is there a way to set a parameter before executing the query to say, hey just read it, even if is dirty, and don't lock anything in the database please?

Comment: If you don't care about locking, pending query changes and the data integrity just load the entities with one of createQuery methods.